# public API for controller filter chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport, actionpack

The code below shows two controllers that have before_filters added in different orders.  As a result, the controllers have different behavior.

When current_user is nil (logged out):

- FooController -> redirects to login_path
- BarController -> redirects to root_path

You could, of course, combine the two methods and make them smarter to make this specific example go away -- but that is missing the point of this question.

The issue at hand is that, in ActionController, **the order that filters get added is relevant**.  (You could also argue that that implementation isn't the greatest, but that's how it is -- so let's move on)

Since that's how ActionController works, I would like to test that behavior.  However, it isn't necessary to test the results of the before filters on each individual action (not DRY).  As far as I can figure, what's actually important is **the resulting order of the filter chain on each action**.

The only thing that `before_filter :require_user` actually does is inject an item into the callback chain - and that's all I should have to test for in my subclasses - that an additional item has been added to the chain.  I don't need to test the effect that `require_user` has on my actions - they can, and should, be stubbed.

That all said, here's the money question: Is there a public API that returns what methods are in a given controller and action's filter chain?  This should include before, after and around filters in their appropriate order.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def require_user
    unless current_user
      redirect_to login_path and return
    end
  end
  def require_admin
    unless current_user.try(:admin?)
      redirect_to root_path and return
    end
  end
end

class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user
  before_filter :require_admin
end

class BarController < ApplicationController

  # reverse the order of the filters

  before_filter :require_admin
  before_filter :require_user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the list of filters via the _process_action_callbacks class method. For a list of filters, you can:

```
FooController._process_action_callbacks.collect &:filter
```

Comment: I was poking around in there.... it's the wild west.  It might be a public method, but I don't get the sense that it's meant to be used as an API.  Not only that, but map(&:filter) doesn't account for the order of before/around filters.